# Custom config files are not loading properly after 9.2 upgrade

Tags: upgrade

We are facing issue in loading the custom config file post 8.2 to 9.2 upgrade.

### Context

We had upgraded our 8.2 instance to 9.2 instance.  Before the upgrade, we had disabled our custom config files. 
Once the upgrade is completed , we enabled the custom config files.

### Problem statement

There are 30 custom config files.(custom1.config to custom30.config) 
Each config file will have a `key value` pair  inside the `DataTemplateconstants` node

While checking the custom config entries file in showconfig.aspx, we found the `key value` pairs are not loaded properly.

**Only the entries in the first custom1.config is loaded.**

Entries from the other files as custom2.config .. custom30.config files are not loaded

Sample structure of config files

Custom1.config file

```
 <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
      <sitecore>
        <DataTemplateConstants>
            Key  Value 1    
            Key  Value 2    
            .
            .
            .
            Key Value 50

        </DataTemplateConstants>
      </sitecore>
    </configuration>
```

Custom2.config file

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <DataTemplateConstants>
        Key  Value 1    
        Key  Value 2    
        .
        .
        .
        Key Value 30

    </DataTemplateConstants>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Custom3.config file

```
 <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
      <sitecore>
        <DataTemplateConstants>
            Key  Value 1    
            Key  Value 2    
            .
            .
            .
            Key Value 15

        </DataTemplateConstants>
      </sitecore>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: keys in all configs are same or different? and what is the folder location for your custom configs?

Comment: Keys in the config files are different. These config files are placed in Include folder.

Comment: Technically it should work but could you also share how you are creating nodes for the key-value?

Comment: Can you provide more details on how your configs are?

Comment: Node for creating the Key Value pair

<FieldName Name="Name1" Value="Value1" />
<FieldName Name="Name2" Value="Value2" />
<FieldName Name="Name3" Value="Value3" />

Comment: Thanks. From the example you provided in the comment, does only the Name1, Value1 that changes? Does the FieldName also change or is it the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following some testing on my local instance, I have been able to reproduce the issue. As you mentioned in the comment, it seems that the only values that are changed are the `Name1` and `Value1` etc...

The only way I have been able to fix it is to make the attributes `Name` and `Value` to be lowercase. Please see result below

**custom1.config**

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <test>
            <FieldName Name="Name4" Value="Value4" />
            <FieldName Name="Name5" Value="Value5" /> 
            <FieldName Name="Name6" Value="Value6" />   
        </test>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

**custom2.config**

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <test>
            <FieldName Name="Name1" Value="Value1" />
            <FieldName Name="Name2" Value="Value2" /> 
            <FieldName Name="Name3" Value="Value3" />           
        </test>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

**Result**

[image]

But if I write the attribute Name and Value as lowercase it works.

**custom1.config**

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <test>
            <FieldName name="Name4" value="Value4" />
            <FieldName name="Name5" value="Value5" /> 
            <FieldName name="Name6" value="Value6" />   
        </test>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

**custom2.config**

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <test>
            <FieldName name="Name1" value="Value1" />
            <FieldName name="Name2" value="Value2" /> 
            <FieldName name="Name3" value="Value3" />           
        </test>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

**Result**

[image]

Need to deep dive into the Sitecore Core functionality to see why the lowercase works compare to the other way. Need to see how Sitecore compiles the configuration files.

Comment: I am also facing Similar issue where only first config is getting loaded but not rest of them  but  I did not understand the solution as pictures of possible solution (Name & Value in lower case) are same as one causing issue. So what has to be lower case exactly

Comment: @AlivorTikos instead of `Name="Name1" Value="Value1"`, it should be `name="Name1" value="Value1"`. It is the attribute that needs to be lowercase

Comment: @HishaamNamooya, Thanks it worked. It was working fine in 8.2 version. Was there any change in the 9.2 version.

Comment: I know that Sitecore had introduces the layers.config but maybe it is an issue internally when it is trying to patch the file. I’ll create a support ticket to see what does sitecore says.